# Jest cannot find node.js "Path" module

Tags: node.js, jestjs, node-modules, ts-jest

I'm trying to use the Node.js "Path" module when testing a function with Jest, but I'm getting an error:

"***TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'join')***"

The part of the code that uses it is

```
import fs from "fs";
import path from "path"; 

const createTempFile = (content) => {
  const tempFilePath = path.join(__dirname, 'temp.txt');
  console.log("tempFilePath", tempFilePath)
  fs.writeFileSync(tempFilePath, content);
  return tempFilePath;
}
```

In the Jest documentation it says that it uses a Node environment by default, so I would expect it to work. I've also double checked the config file and there is nothing different set up.

Anybody faced this?

Comment: why don't you add a bare minimum test code too, So people can reproduce. I tried but seems to work without any issue.

Comment: It crashes at this line, so there is nothing more to add. It doesn't even reach the rest of the code. 

**const tempFilePath = path.join(__dirname, 'temp.txt');**